# ASP.NET MVC Routing to ignore all routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In ASP.NET MVC you ignore routes by adding to the `RouteCollection`; (In the RouteConfig or Global.asax.cs) either instructing it to ignore a route or by specifying where matched route requests should go.

If one wanted to:

- Specifying explicitly every route to handle
- Ignoring all other routes (Let the URL rewriting feature of IIS rewrite the routes that did not explicitly match)

What would the string be to make ASP.NET MVC routing ignore all requests? As the routes are matched sequentially making the default path (the last specified) ignore all routes I can only make my server respond to explicit routes I have defined.

Comment: IIS will handle routes before MVC will, so I'm not sure that you can let IIS handle all the routes that MVC does not

Comment: @jumpingcode that sounds right, it's just that in an article I found http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/ they mention that MVC will interrupt url rewriting as it will claim the route before ARR gets to it. Weird

Comment: Oh really? That sounds interesting

Comment: @jumpingcode yeah, so do you know how to write the ignore code?